# The process cannot acces the file

Tags: c#

I have this error when my program read the line `File.Delete("upv/version.txt");`, but I don't know where the problem is and how to resolve it. Can somebody help me?

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\WpfApp1\WpfApp1\bin\Debug\upv\version.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            btnPlay.IsEnabled = false; 

            if (VerifyVersion())
                btnPlay.IsEnabled = true;
            else

                Download("http://localhost/","text.rar"); 

        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Game.exe");
        }

        private void ProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {

        }

        private string VersionActuelle;

                private bool VerifyVersion()
        {
            StreamReader VersionReader = new StreamReader("upv/version.txt");
            string VersionClient = VersionReader.ReadToEnd();

            VersionClient = VersionClient.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

            VersionActuelle = ReadRemoteTextFile("http://localhost/upv/version.txt");

            VersionActuelle = VersionActuelle.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

            if (VersionActuelle == VersionClient)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private string ReadRemoteTextFile(string Url)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(Url); 

            WebRequest wRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri); 

            WebResponse wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse(); 

            Stream ResponseStream = wResponse.GetResponseStream(); 

            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream); 

            string Temp = sReader.ReadToEnd();

            return Temp;
        }

        private void Download(string Url, string DownloadTo)
        {
            WebClient wClient = new WebClient(); 


            wClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(UpdateProgressChange);  


            wClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(UpdateDone); 


            wClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Url), DownloadTo); 


        }

        private void UpdateProgressChange(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
        }

        private void UpdateDone(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Mise à jour terminée! Vous pouvez désormais jouer.", "Notification");
            btnPlay.IsEnabled = true;

            File.Delete("upv/version.txt");

            using(System.IO.TextWriter sWriter = File.CreateText("upv/version.txt"))
            {
                sWriter.Write(VersionActuelle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you are using **StreamReader** or  **StreamWriter** do call **Dispose** to close that particular instance and you won't find the error happening again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are using **StreamReader** or **StreamWriter** do call **Dispose** to close that particular instance and you won't find the error happening again.

In your case,

```
string VersionClient = VersionReader.ReadToEnd();
VersionReader.Dispose();
```

And

```
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(ResponseStream); 
string Temp = sReader.ReadToEnd();
sReader.Dispose();
```

Edit : You don't need to close the StreamWriter instance when using **Using** as it automatically gets flushed

Comment: Glad i could help you. Just as a tip. If you use File class for Read & Write operations you don't need to do the Dispose/Close call. As they are Static by default and you can directly call them without having to create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose the file.. when you read the file in the VerifyVersion method. You need to put a VersionReader.Close(); o better if you use a Using clause for dispose the file..